# Does HttpClient's PostMethod.addParameter() add encoded form parameters or URL query parameters?

Tags: java, httpclient

In HttpClient 3.0.x, does the "PostMethod.addParameter()" method add a form parameter, or does it add a URL query parameter?  I think it's the former, but I need to be sure.  There are limits on the length of a URL that are less than the limits on POSTed data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It adds it to the request body (as expected). Here's the [Javadoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/):

```
addParameter

public void addParameter(String paramName,
                         String paramValue)
                  throws IllegalArgumentException
Adds a new parameter to be used in the POST request body.
```